# Exception while starting jetty 9 from Ant and Ivy

Tags: ant, jetty, jndi

I am trying to start Jetty 9 from Ant using ivy (not maven) and getting the following exception

Object of class 'org.eclipse.jetty.ant.WebApplicationProxyImpl.AntWebAppContext' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'. Object Class and type Class are from different loaders.

jetty-env.xml ---

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="jdbc/datasource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.inet.tds.TdsDataSource">
            <!--<Set name="driverClassName">com.inet.tds.TdsDriver</Set>-->
            <Set name="serverName">serverDetails
            </Set>
            <Set name="user">user</Set>
            <Set name="password">password</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

If I change the class in the Configure form "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" to "org.eclipse.jetty.ant.WebApplicationProxyImpl.AntWebAppContext", getting the ClassNotFoundException org.eclipse.jetty.ant.WebApplicationProxyImpl.AntWebAppContext - Even though I have the jar included in my classpath.

Comment: I have been working on updating this since we pulled it over from codehaus in the last week or so.  I'll see if I can get a unit test going using the ant webapp context and see we can get a proper answer.